# Set breaks of axis by level of factor in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axes

Given a plot where the x axis is discrete, given by a ordered factor, like this plot:

[image]

with the levels:

```
D E F G H I J
1 1 1 2 2 3 4
```

Is there a way to do:

```
scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("D","G", "I", "J"), lables=c(1,2,3,4))
```

without manually copying the breaks?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
keeps<-c(1,4,6,7) # Indices for levels you want to show
ggplot(data=diamonds)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=color,y=carat),stat="identity")+
  scale_x_discrete(
    breaks=levels(d$color)[keeps],
    labels=table(d$color)[keeps])
```

Comment: The problem here is that I have to manually pick the breaks, I.e. c(1,4,6,7) in this example. I referred to it as "manually copying the breaks" in my question. Is there any dynamic way to group the ticks by the levels of a factor?

Comment: How are you picking the levels?

Comment: The idea is to place the breaks when the level of the factor changes. G would be the first one with level 2, I first one with 3, J first one with 4. Thus D,G,I,J